# NavigationBar is under the statusbar on iOS 9 and 10

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I've been developing an app for the past few months, and I was always testing on my iOS 11 device and simulators. Since we are close to public release, I decided to test the app on iOS 9 and 10 simulators to make sure everything is ok.

To my disapointment, the core element of the app is broken: Its an app that displays a list of articles in tableviews, using a TabBarController. More article categories can be accessed through the side menu. However, when I display a VC form the side menu, for which I create the VC, embed it in a NavigationController and then add it in the TabBarController and make it the selected tab, the NavBar is under the status bar and the tableview's content insets extend under the tabBar, which also breaks my TabBar and creates a whole lot of other problems.

The weird thing is that after navigating to the next VC, the whole statusbar situation is fixed, so I'm guessing something is initially off with the NavBar that gets fixed once a second VC is pushed.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this bug? On iOS 11 everything works perfectly, while on iOS 9 and 10 only when a new VC is pushed, the error is fixed. Please note that I'm not using a UITableViewController but a ViewCOntroller with an embeded TableView, since I also need to add othr views at the bottom of my view controller.

Comment: You’re right that iOS 11 is very different, largely because of the safe area and changes in view controllers and views (like scroll views and table views) because of it. You might need to write a lot of conditional code in order to get backwards compatibility. Or just give up on backwards compatibility and make your Deployment Target iOS 11.

Comment: Plus many metrics changed a lot in iOS 11, including tab bars.

Comment: I see... I've been trying to figure this out for more than 3 days now. Any suggestions on how to get this to work on iOS 10? I am using a normal UINavigationController but its initial position is broken... However, the NavigationControllers already in the TabBarController are placed correctly. Only the new ones are problematic.

Comment: Sorry, I can’t make sense of the description so I don’t grasp the details of what you’re actually doing. Your question includes no code. It sounds a bit like a misuse of a tab bar controller (they are not usually dynamic), but it’s hard to tell so far.

Comment: My case is indeed misuse of a tab bar controller, but this is what was requested (more tabs, on a scrollable TabBar without a "more" tab). I managed to workarount the faulty behaviour by adding a small delay (200ms) from when I add the new VC to the TabBar and when I set the selectedIndex of the TabBarController to the new VC's index, and now the NavigtionControllers are being layed down correctly. Thank you for your the information you've given me @matt

Comment: Great work! [I cannot help feeling, however, that you should have used a UIPageViewController here, as what you're describing sounds like exactly the sort of thing it is for.] — If you don't want to spend any more time on this question, you might want to delete it, so that it isn't left hanging. On the other hand, it is perfectly legal to answer your own question (and in 48 hours you can even accept your answer), and you might like to do that instead, as this might help others. Up to you. Thanks for reporting back!